# Open internal URL(edge://...) by command line

Tags: windows, chromium, microsoft-edge, protocol

I can open an URL by command line.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe" http://example.com //works
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe" edge://settings //works not
```

Is there an other way, or is it impossible?

Comment: You need Admin Credentials to access that folder. Did you try that?  Normal (standard) user cannot run this command.

Comment: That protocol is not registered with the system., so it only makes sense to Edge when Edge is already running. I don't know if there's a way to register the "edge://" protocol with the system, but I'd look into doing that myself as a first step toward the solution you're looking for.

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389204/how-do-i-create-my-own-url-protocol-e-g-so

Comment: @John It's not the problem.

Comment: @music2myear The command doesn't work, the protocol registration want use this command too.

Comment: I'd assume as much. These internal URIs may be, for security reasons, not processed as incoming commands at all by the application, and are only allowed to be accessed from within the browser already running. If configuring a new URI entry doesn't work, then this will not work as you want it to. There's still a chance a 3rd party utility such as Auto Hotkey may allow you to run the process as two different steps, one to open the program, and one to access the URI.

Comment: @music2myear I want a command but if it's not possible, that's it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe this is possible. These are URIs and they can be registered with the operating system in order to be called, but there appears to be a limit in the Chromium-based browsers preventing them from being called from outside the browser. I would imagine this is for security reasons.

While it may be possible to build a multi-step process in something sort as Auto Hotkey that would accomplish this, it is not directly possible from within a command interpreter or shell in Windows such as CMD or PowerShell.

Comment: How about delete comments on the question?
It's a job for?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you believe they ought to be deleted?